# How to get rid of sequel error in sequel?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sequel

here's my code:

init file:

```
require 'sequel'
DB = Sequel.connect('sqlite://data.db')

DB.drop_table?(:restaurants)
DB.create_table :restaurants do
primary_key :id
String :name
end

DB.drop_table?(:category)
DB.create_table :category do
primary_key :id
String :name
end


DB.drop_table?(:items)
DB.create_table :items do
primary_key :id
foreign_key :restaurant_id
foreign_key :category_name
String :name
Float :price
end

require_relative './restaurant'
require_relative './categories'
require_relative './item'
```

app file:

```
require_relative './models/init

p = Category.create(:name => 'Pizza')
c = Category.create(:name => 'Calazone')
pa = Category.create(:name => 'Pasta')
s = Category.create(:name => 'Salad')
d = Category.create(:name => 'Dessert')
dr = Category.create(:name => 'Drink')
si = Category.create(:name => 'Side')`
```

But I am getting this error:

```
/home/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/sequel-3.45.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:1780:in `block in set_restricted': method name= doesn't exist (Sequel::Error)
    from /home/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/sequel-3.45.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:1767:in `each'
    from /home/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/sequel-3.45.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:1767:in `set_restricted'
    from /home/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/sequel-3.45.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:1278:in `set'
    from /home/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/sequel-3.45.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:1736:in `initialize_set'
    from /home/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/sequel-3.45.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:920:in `initialize'
    from /home/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/sequel-3.45.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:156:in `new'
    from /home/ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/sequel-3.45.0/lib/sequel/model/base.rb:156:in `create'
    from app.rb:4:in `<main>'"
```

Help Please.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't post your Category model, but I'm guessing it's not actually looking at the category table (probably the categories table).  You either want to rename your database table to categories or tell your Category model to use the category table.  If that's not it, you probably want to post your model code.